# Are Technic and Education sets overpriced because they're "educational"?

Tags: technic, motor, education

It seems like to get a Technic set of any substantial size costs hundreds of dollars. It's kind of insane. Technic is marketed as "educational". Sometimes I wonder if The LEGO Group is assuming all parents who value educational toys are loaded.

I realize LEGO can be pricey in general, for various reasons. But whether you measure it by weight in plastic or number of pieces, *does being Technic or Education make sets more expensive on average?*

Of course we have to take into account when a set has a motor or other *electrical* parts, but I've seen sets that are all plastic, seeming to be priced above average, possibly just because they have a lot of gears and other "machine" parts.

Comment: In order to make this question answerable more details are needed. Especially which sets you have in mind. There could be reasons why certain sets are valued higher or lower, compared to others, some (but not all) of the reasons could be: age, size, distribution area, production numbers, and so on. Another thing to mention is that Technic isn't the same as Education as they are targeting different audiences. It would be nice to have country/region mentioned as well, since it is known that various themes have different interest in each region, which could affect the pricing as well.

Comment: @Alex Okay, all fair points. I will try to provide some more examples and expand my question. It might not happen today though, so please bear with me.